# Why do I have a reauth=1 redirection loop when I try to log in to WordPress hosted on AWS Fargate?

Tags: login, amazon

I have set up an AWS Fargate cluster with ten WordPress containers behind an AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB).

I tested that my settings work when I have one container. Why can I not log in when I have ten containers?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out that the login flow is interrupted because the second HTTP request usually goes to a different container than the container that delivered the `wp-login.php` login form.

The solution is to turn on [Sticky Sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) for the AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) Target Group that serves the Fargate containers.